# How are calendar overlays supposed to work?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calendar

Verbose background information is provided, with questions in **bold**.

We're working with Foundation 2010, and I'm running into some calendar overlay issues that are quite non-intuitive, so I'm trying to get a better understanding of what's supposed to happen. Unfortunately, a google search of "calendar overlay" leads to countless articles about inegrating Outlook or Exchange with SP.

My calendars are at

```
http://sharepoint.domain.com/demo/Lists/Event%20Calendar.aspx, 
http://sharepoint.domain.com/demo/Lists/TestCal.aspx, 
http://sharepoint.domain.com/demo/Lists/TeamMeetings.aspx,
http://sharepoint.domain.com/demo/Lists/Training.aspx
```

and I have created `http://sharepoint.domain.com/demo/Lists/main.aspx` as a "master calendar" into which all for of the above calendars should be overlaid.

When I insert the "main" calendar webpart, I see the button in the ribbon for overlay, as well as a link in the left sidebar for calendar overlay. However, clicking on either of those yields a blank list, even though I have the four calendars on my site in the same path. I need to "add" all the calendars I want to see.

All calendars are SP calendars created from within the site ("Site Settings > New > Calendar"), no exchange servers are involved.

**Is this normal behavior? Am I supposed to have to add the calendars to appear in the overlay, or should the list populate with calendars in my list library from which I just need to select?**

Once I've added the additional calendars for overlay and visit my "original" calendar, all of the overlaid calendars are listed in the left navigation. I can view my calendar, but only events from the calendar I'm CURRENTLY viewing (none of the events from the overlays) will show up. Interestingly if I click through to an individual calendar, I can see all of that calendar's events.

**Is there some other view I need to access, some other property I need to set, or SOMETHING on my end that will allow me to view these events?**

Things I've discovered so far:

- I've got site admin access

  All permissions are set appropriately

  I get the same results whether I add & edit a new calendar from within the "new Calendar" path or add via Site Actions, new calendar.

**Has anyone else experienced similar problems? How were they resolved?"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to create an events list or use one of your existing events lists to be the "roll-up" one.  You configure this events list to display it and the other events lists.  Only when accessing this events list's calendar (month,week,day) view will you see the events from the other events lists overlayed.

Yes, when you overlay calendars, you have to put in the url to the web if it is different than the current web.  Then you have to click resolve.  Select your events list from the drop down.  Pick a color and add.

In my experience with this, they do show up when viewing the calendar view of the events list that you set it up on.

Comment: Are you using actual event lists for your events, or do you have events in a calendar? or are calendars just a flavor of event lists? Right now, I have a master calendar into which all the others are overlaid...no events apart from those in the master calendar. Every calendar is in the same list on the same site, all with the same URL-except for the filename, of course-but THOSE don't show up in the list of available calendars for overlay. I'm just really confused because Im ~expecting~ to see what you describe and I'm not.

Comment: A calendar is a view type, not a list type.  The list type is called an events list.  You can add a calendar view to any type of list that has at least one datetime column, but a calendar view is setup automatically when you create an events list.  An events lists is also required to connect the list to an outlook calendar.  So to verify, are all of your "calendars" different event lists or are they other types of lists?

Comment: When you say they are all the same url except for the filename, this concerns me.  Can you post the urls you are referring to (you can remove the domain name if you'd like)?

Comment: OK...that makes sense. I created four separate lists by going to "Site Actions > New > Calendar" so I would assume that I have four discrete lists. I can see a line item for all of them in "all Site Content"'s list section as well.

Comment: http://sharepoint.domain.com/demo/Lists/* and then the calendar names -- Event%20Calendar.aspx, TestCal.aspx, TeamMeetings.aspx, and Training.aspx -- all appear in place of the *. All the calendars are in the same path...lists within the site "Demo"

Comment: Answered your questions, and clarified my post to incorporate those details. :)

Comment: Those urls look very strange to me.  My calendar urls look more like this:  http://sharepoint.domain.com/site/Lists/Calendar/calendar.aspx

Comment: Notice the structure has the list name and then the viewname and then .aspx:

/Lists/ListName/ViewName.aspx